# Finding the depth of a binary tree- where is the depth being stored/updated?

Tags: python, recursion

I have found a solution to find the maximum depth of a binary tree:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if not root:return 0
        l=self.maxDepth(root.left)
        r=self.maxDepth(root.right)
        return(max(l,r)+1)
```

While I understand what is happening in terms of the recursion, I fail to see how the depth is being recorded with each recursive call- where is the depth being stored? Like in an iterative solution, the depth is explicitly recorded/updated and returned.

Comment: The depth is not getting stored for the child nodes. In this piece of code, the max depth is being returned for child nodes and getting accumulated on the parent node. Because from outside, you could be calling it on the top level root node, you only see that as output.

Comment: Ohh, so am I right in understanding that 'l' and 'r' record the number of recursive calls?

Comment: ```l``` will store the depths of the sub-trees where the root node is ```l```. Similarly ```r```. You will understand it better if you trace this code using Recursion stack.

Comment: I see! I understand now, in terms of l and r being passed as arguments. But I still don't see how the depth itself is being recorded, could you please explain this? Do l and r represent integers?

Comment: Integers that get incremented each time a recursive call is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxDepth` returns an `int` which is the depth of the tree you called it on.`l` and `r` are each the result of a call to `maxDepth`, so clearly they are each the depth of a tree.

In particular, `l` is the depth of the left subtree, and `r` is the depth of the right subtree.

Then we just return `max(l, r) + 1`, because whichever subtree was deeper, the depth of the whole tree is one more than that depth. There's no need to store anything anywhere else; that's the answer `maxDepth` was charged with computing! `l` and `r` are each a complete final result for a *subproblem* (the maximum depth in a smaller subtree), and we combine them together to make a solution to the whole problem (the maximum depth in the whole tree).

If you trace through the execution one step at a time, you will find that when the recursive subcalls are made, you need to "remember" all the local variables because you'll need them again when the subcall returns. Since each subcall can have more subcalls in the middle of it, there ends up being multiple sets of local variables "live" at once (that's exactly what a stack frame is, if you've heard of that). So you can think of those multiple sets of `l` and `r` as being "where the depth is stored". However each individual call doesn't need to do anything to store its local variables anywhere, just the fact that you're calling a function creates a set of its local variables, and the fact that you're calling the same function multiple times before it finishes means that multiple sets are live at once.

In an iterative solution you need to explicitly build a data structure that "remembers" information as you work through the tree. The recursive solution just uses the function call stack to do the same thing, because local variables get created for each recursive call.

It's worth noting that if you are having trouble seeing how this works, it probably means you have the wrong mental model for how function calls work. Recursive calls use **exactly** the same rules that non-recursive calls do, so if your mental model for function calls has trouble with recursive calls, you probably need to rethink how you think about functions in general.

Answer (score 0):

Trying running it in your mind, step-by-step. Imagine you have a perfectly balanced tree of depth 3: so you have a root node, 2 1st-level subnodes, 4 2nd-level subnodes.

You visit the root node, and make 2 recursive calls, respectively on the left and right child - the calls will return two values, you keep the largest (but since the tree is balanced they are equal, and we know they amount to 2), add 1 because you want to include the root node itself, and return the depth (3).

Let's see the first recursive call, on the left child of root: once again you make 2 recursive calls on the children; once again we know they will both return 1, we add 1 and return 2 to the caller. The call on the right child does the same, of course.

Now we go for the left child of the left 1st level subnode, ok? Once more, you call the function on its children, but since they are `None` this time the function immediately returns zero, so you take zero, add 1 as usual, and return it.

Summing up the function will have been called:

- 1x on the root node (not recursively)
- 2x on the 2 1st level subnodes (recursively)
- 4x on the 2nd level subnodes (recursively)
- 8x on the non-existing 3rd level subnodes (recursively)

so in general for a perfectly balanced tree of depth `N` your function will have been called `2**(N+1)-1` times.

Comment: Thanks Gimix, my issue is not with following the recursion calls- that much is clear to me. Rather what I am struggling to see is how the depth is being recorded- so every time there is a recursion call (left side), does 'L' increase by 1?

Comment: You mentioned " You visit the root node, and make 2 recursive calls, respectively on the left and right child - the calls will return two values"

Comment: What 'values' are being returned??

Comment: The values are integers, and are the depth of the subtree. Is it clear to you that each instance of the function has its own copy of the local variables?

Comment: Hi Gimix, I see it now! I was struggling to understand how left_heigh and right_height became numbers, but I see now that when we get to the leaf nodes and hit the base case, that left_height and right_height become 0, and the depth gets passed upwards and grows (by 1) as we untangle the recursion stack!

Comment: But I could only see this by writing it out, I am worried that I would not be able to produce this recursion code myself to answer problems, will this come with practice, or do I need to memorise some solutions and adapt it?

Comment: Sorry, one other thing, I am used to the recursion being called by return maxDepth(...), or just 'left_height=maxDepth(root.left)' - is it necessary to have the 'self' in this case and in other cases, and if so, why?

Comment: It is just practice. Two typical recursion algorithms you may want to try are the factorial (single recursion) and the Fibonacci series (double recursion like the one here). `Self` has nothing to do with the recursion, it's needed here because `maxDepth` is defined as a method of the class `Solution` - if it were a standalone function `self` would not be requested

Comment: Ah, and if this was useful you may want to accept the answer ;)